# Read data from a bluetooth barcode reader in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, barcode-scanner

I want to read barcodes using a bluetooth barcode scanner. 
I don't want to use Bluetooth Keyboard Emulation (HID) mode, because is too hard to point to a textbox before any scan.

I read this [developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) but I don't found yet something usable.
Must listen for an write event with a end-code delimiter (CR, LF, etc).

Comment: I never thought for a moment that it might be your responsibility :) This is the problem I face now and I think may be one of general interest. As are all the posts on this site. If you want to be mean to someone please pay attention in your own backyard!

Comment: I am not at all being mean, I am just pointing out that this is the wrong site for you to post this question. The purpose of this site to help people fix problems in their code and not to tell people how to do stuff. So if you don't have a specific problems with a piece of code you are on the wrong site and your question will neither be well received nor answered any time soon.

Answer (score 3):

If your bluetooth barcode scanner does not have a switch* for change HID mode to SSP mode, then you can't connect with him. (* hardware or software switch)

Android connect natively with HID bluetooth (Human Interface Device) and don't let them go :).

So, I solve my problem reading and overriding a keyboard event.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if  (barCodeRadearIsOn && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || (event.getKeyCode() >= 7 && event.getKeyCode() <= 16))) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
                Toast.makeText(context, barCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ....... .......

                barCode = "";
            }
        } else {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
                barCode = barCode + (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- barCodeRadearIsOn  - users have a switch on/off
- This code "intercept" only Enter and numeric characters from 0 to 9.

Comment: not working, I've tried onKeyDown, dispatchKeyEvent, onKeyListener, all not working, my edittext in fragment

Comment: Use a bluetooth 1D/2D barcode scanner with SPP - Serial Port Profile and read the serial bluetooth communication.